# How do i utilize my knockout.js ViewModel in my View?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have been assigned this task to correct the googlemaps directions url.

Currently, the map directs the user from the current GeoLocation, not the entered zip code (new location ... lat and long).

Here is my ViewModel

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.map = null;
    self.currentLocation = {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
    };

    self.geocode = function () {
        if (!self.isValid()) {
            self.zipCode(self.previousZipCode);
        } else {
            self.previousZipCode = self.zipCode();
        }

        // Take the updated zip code and geocode it into lat/long
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': self.zipCode() }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                var newLocation = {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: lng
                };

                if (self.currentLocation.latitude == newLocation.latitude && self.currentLocation.longitude == newLocation.longitude) return;
                self.currentLocation = newLocation;

                self.reload();
```

Then, in the View ... I just don't know how to get the currentLocation value in my markup (View)

```
  <a data-bind="attr: {'href' : 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/**Current+Location**/' + Latitude + ',' + Longitude, 'data-track' : 'Find a Location', 'data-track-action' : 'directions', 'data-track-label' : ItemName }" target="_blank" class="locations-icon flex-item uppercase">
                            <i class="material-icons">directions</i><br />
                            directions
                        </a>
```

Comment: Just do `...maps/dir/' + currentLocation.latitude + ',' + currentLocation.longitude`. Although, it you're planning on that value changing then you should consider making it an [observable.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

Comment: Like @MikeC states you are not dealing with observables. There is no need to use Knockout for this, the way you are doing it. Have your ViewModel prepare the URL so that the URL is updated when location changes.

Comment: Thank you guys ... I kind of thought this might be the case, but I didn't write this and the person that did is fairly knowledgeable so I assumed they set it up correctly.